# Direct limit of functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, functions, limits-colimits

Let $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ be a directed system of functions $f_j: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ over the directed set $I$. Is there a good way to give a meaning to "direct limit" of this system ?

What are examples where this *is* possible ?

One can represent an $f_i$ by its graph $\{ (x,f_i(x)) \vert x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and then apply the classical definition of direct limit, but is there one well-defined way to make the limit into a function $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Directed systems can be defined in any category. If you want to use this concept for functions $f_j$, you have to **define** a category whose objects are functions $f$ (maybe only functions $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) - but what are the morphisms $\phi : f \to g$? Commutative squares or something else? When you identify $f_i$ with its graph $G_i$ you have the same problem: What are the bonding maps $G_i  \to G_j$?

Comment: @PaulFrost : commuting squares, or, for instance, homotopies (if we consider only continuous functions). In both cases, it seems to me that any (continuous) function deserves to be called "direct limit," and that is not what I want. Ideally, if ${(f_n)}_n$ is a directed set over, say, $\mathbb{N}$, which converges to some function $f$ in a classical, analytic, way, I would like the directed set to have a limit which coincides with $f$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about ["directed set"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) in the same sense as the Wikipedia entry, it makes perfect sense to speak of *directed limit*.

This is already a well-established concept in topology. E is used to extend the concept of limits of sequences in topological spaces in such a way that analogous theorems for sequences in metric spaces are also valid (with due abstractions) in topological spaces.

See [General Topology (Graduate Texts in Mathematics) by John L. Kelley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387901256)

Comment: Can you explain, in my example, how the limit looks like as a function $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$?